# Probability of an event in R

Tags: r, probability

I've the following data frame:

[image]

and I need to evaluate the probability that a student is a "M", i. e. P("M") equal to the ratio between the number of the "M" and the number of studenti. I did it in this way:

```
nStudenti <- length(studenti$sesso)
tabellaSesso <- table(studenti$sesso)
nMaschi <- tabellaSesso[names(tabellaSesso) == "M"]
P = nMaschi / nStudenti
```

Is this the shortest way or there are commands which simply the things?

Comment: `mean(studenti$sesso == "M")`

Comment: @RobinGertenbach's comment solves it and if you want the probabilities for both sexes, `tabellaSesso/sum(tabellaSesso)`.

Comment: Hello @RobinGertenbach I tried your command and the output is NA

Comment: If the result is `NA`, try `mean(studenti$sesso == "M", na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: now it works @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table()` to get the absolute frequencies and then use `prop.table()` to get the probabilities. If you are only interested in a specific value like `"M"`, you can just index that value.

```r
# sample data
studenti <- data.frame(sesso = sample(c("M", "F", NA), 100, replace = TRUE))

# all probabilties
prop.table(table(studenti$sesso))
#> 
#>        F        M 
#> 0.530303 0.469697

# specfic probability 
prop.table(table(studenti$sesso))["M"]
#>        M 
#> 0.469697
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function

```
#Function
    propCond=function(VAR,MODALITY){
      PROP=sum(VAR==MODALITY,na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(VAR),na.rm=TRUE)
      return(PROP)
    }

#Result
    propCond(c("a","a","b"),"a")
```